# Регулярное выражение поиска кода в строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражение

Имеем строку текста, в ней могут быть даты, цифры и нужный код вида **xxx-xxx**, его нужно вернуть.

Условие поиска: начинается код с пробела, заканчивается пробелом или концом строки, состоит только из цифр и дефиса. Помогите составить. Спасибо.

Comment: Приведите примеры строк, которые должны находиться

Answer (score 2):

шаблон поиска:

```
(?<=\s|^)\d{3}-\d{3}(?=\s|$)
```

Где:
`(?<=\s|^)` -  позитивный просмотр назад на любой пробельный символ, либо начало строки
`\d{3}-\d{3}` - три цифры, дефис, три цифры
`(?=\s|$)` - позитивный просмотр вперед на любой пробельный символ, либо конец строки

---

Автоматический код созданный на сайте: [regexp101](https://regex101.com/r/mzjbvc/1/codegen?language=php)

```php
$re = '/(?<=\s|^)\d{3}-\d{3}(?=\s|$)/m';
$str = '123-321
ewq 555-848 dsdw
dww555-555wqqwe
dww555-555 wqqwe
dww 555-555wqqwe
dww 555-555';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```